# Clear image from windows store app

Tags: c#, image, windows-store-apps

I'm inserting an image to my windows store app by function:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            using(IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {

                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);

                ImageBox.Source = bitmapImage;
            }            
        }
    }
```

I want to have a method that will clear the image from my `ImageBox`.  Doing some research on Google I found to use:

```
ImageBox.Image = false;
```

There is no `*.image` property in my `ImageBox`, how else I can implement that?

Comment: Try: `ImageBox.Source = null;`

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer in the comment works:

```
ImageBox.Source = null;
```